# How to make Bokeh button invoke a function (using CustomJS)

Tags: python, bokeh

I am able to get the functionality with curdoc option and then using 'bokeh serve bokehcode.py' and then having my flask code (call it app.py) refer to this bokeh plot.
But I need to have a single python code that includes bokeh part as well, and I am running in to an issue in making the button click to invoke the function that updates my plot/figure. I have spent the whole day without much luck.

For the sake of simplicity i have removed all the functionality (even the Flask part) and put a simplified code below, which I need working **without curdoc** option (so mostly with customjs callback?). I can then extend it to my functionality.

```
from bokeh.models.widgets import TextInput,Button,Paragraph
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.plotting import figure

inptxt = TextInput()
displaytxt = Paragraph()
button = Button()

p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)
def myfunc():
    displaytxt.text=inptxt.value
    p.xaxis.axis_label = inptxt.value

button.on_click(myfunc)
layout=column(inptxt,displaytxt,button,p)

curdoc().add_root(layout)
```

In my actual code there will be a lot things 'myfunc()' will do, including some machine learning stuff and then it will update the plots. I would like this myfunc to be invoked when the button is clicked and also update the figure(p), and i would like it to be achieved without using curdoc. Any help on how to do this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need to get rid of `curdoc` in the first place?

Comment: I am looking to have a single python program which can be launched and managed, instead of having to deal with a flask server and a bokeh server. Also, I don't know how to deal with bokeh + flask when deploying using Zappa. But, any tips on how to solve my above issue?

Comment: You can use `curdoc` in standalone scripts or in apps that embed Bokeh as a library just fine. Your code should work as is, especially given that callbacks are orthogonal to the usage of `curdoc`. Unless you mean that you don't want to use _any_ server, including the one created by `bokeh serve`. Meaning, you only want to use static HTML files. In that case yes, you need to use `CustomJS` and to rewrite your Python callback code into JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks Eugene. Yes, i meant not having to use bokeh server at all. I don't know CustomJS but if someone can give the equivalent customjs version for the above code i can try to extend it to my full code. Hope it clarifies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, TextInput, Button, Paragraph
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show

inptxt = TextInput()
displaytxt = Paragraph()
button = Button()

p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400,
           # Note that without setting the initial label,
           # setting it with the button will not make it
           # visible unless you interact with the plot, e.g.
           # by panning it. I've created
           # https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/10362
           # for this.
           x_axis_label='hello')
p.circle(0, 0)  # To avoid having a blank plot.


def myfunc():
    displaytxt.text = inptxt.value
    p.xaxis.axis_label = inptxt.value


button.js_on_click(CustomJS(args=dict(inptxt=inptxt,
                                      displaytxt=displaytxt,
                                      # Need `[0]` because `p.xaxis` is actually
                                      # a "splattable list" that BokehJS doesn't support.
                                      xaxis=p.xaxis[0]),
                            code="""\
                                displaytxt.text = inptxt.value;
                                xaxis.axis_label = inptxt.value;
                            """))
show(column(inptxt, displaytxt, button, p))
```

Comment: Hi Eugene, any chance you will be able to help with this related issue which has become a dead end: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63246636/how-to-update-source-of-bokeh-downloadbutton-from-a-function-that-is-invoked-by

Comment: Sorry, no idea.