# How to update source of bokeh downloadbutton from a function that is invoked by a widget

Tags: python-3.x

How to update source of a downloadbutton of Bokeh? In my case, I am calling update() when other widgets are being invoked. The update() function is also the place i will update 'df_updated' dataframe which needs to be downloaded but only when the downloadbutton is clicked. Any help on this is appreciated.

```
def update()
   # some process...
   df_updated = <whatever>

downloadbutton.js_on_click(CustomJS(args=dict(source=source),
                            code=open(join(dirname(__file__), "download.js")).read()))

myselect.on_click(update)
```

I tried something like this but it didn't update source of downloadbutton:

```
dl_source = something # initialize
def update()
   global dl_source
   # some process...
   df_updated = <whatever>
   dl_source = ColumnDataSource(df_updated)

downloadbutton.js_on_click(CustomJS(args=dict(source=dl_source),
                            code=open(join(dirname(__file__), "download.js")).read()))

myselect.on_click(update)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a way. Inside the function where the dataframe was getting updated, we need to use source.data = and not source =

Here is how it should look:

```
df=pd.DataFrame()
source = ColumnDataSource(df) # initialize to whatever u want

def update()
   # some process...
   df_updated = <whatever>
   cds = ColumnDataSource(df_updated)
   source.data = dict(cds.data)  # this is what was the difference in the end

downloadbutton.js_on_click(CustomJS(args=dict(source=source),
                            code=open(join(dirname(__file__), "download.js")).read()))

myselect.on_click(update) # call update() to update the df
```